# How to mock modelMapper as Function?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5, modelmapper

I'm writing a unit test for a method in my service and I'm strugling to handle its return.

Here's my service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class CategoryService {

private final PaginationGenerator paginationGenerator;
private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

@Autowired
public CategoryService(final PaginationGenerator paginationGenerator, final ModelMapper modelMapper){
        this.paginationGenerator = paginationGenerator;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
}

public PageableResponse<CategoryDto> getAll(final Integer page, final Integer pageSize, String idCategory, String name) {
        final Pageable pageRequest = this.paginationGenerator.pageRequest(page, pageSize);
        final Page<Category> categoryPage = getCategoriesByParams(idCategory, name, pageRequest);
        return this.paginationGenerator.paginatedResponse(categoryPage, category -> modelMapper.map(category, CategoryDto.class));
    }
}
```

this categoryPage is fulfilled properly by getCategoriesByParams method.
The problem occurs when it tries to convert and return the PageableResponse, because this modelMapper just won't work.

Here's my unit test

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class CategoryServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CategoryService categoryService;
    @Mock
    private ModelMapper mockedModelMapper;
    @Mock
    private PaginationGenerator mockedPaginationGenerator;

    @Test
    void getAll() {
        Page<Category> categoryPage = new PageImpl<>(generateListOfCategories());
        Pageable pageable = Pageable.ofSize(50);

        when(mockedPaginationGenerator.pageRequest(0, 50)).thenReturn(pageable);
        when(categoryRepository.findAll(pageable)).thenReturn(categoryPage);
        //when(mockedPaginationGenerator.paginatedResponse(categoryPage)).thenReturn(gene);
        when(mockedModelMapper.map(Category.class, CategoryDto.class)).thenReturn(generateCategoryDto());

        PageableResponse<CategoryDto> categoriesReturned = categoryService.getAll(0, 50, null, null);

        assertEquals(categoriesReturned.getContent().size(), categoryPage.getContent().size());
        verify(categoryRepository, times(1)).findAll(pageable);

    }
}
```

This modelMapper as a function is hard to figure out how to test, I'm not sure if the problem is the way of mocking modelMappers and paginationGenerator or I'm just missing something.

categoriesReturned always returns as null in my test, so I can't do the assertions with it.

How could I perform this test? or is there another way of testing it?

Comment: You are mapping a Category to CategoryDto in your prod code, but when stubbing you pass in Category.class instead of a Category (or appropriate ArgumentMatcher)

Comment: I think it might be simpler for you just to change your mocked ModelMapper to a Spy instead since it will then call the correct methods without you needing to do anything